# Formatting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm having an issue formatting in pandas. 
Any ideas? If this has been asked before please let me know and please point me to where! 
The return type doesn't matter to me as long as its formatted along the lines of what I have down there. 
I have the following where the numbers are the index in this case, New is my column.

```
   New
3  A
2  A
4  B
5  C
8  C
```

I want

```
A
3 2 
B
4 
C
5 8
```

Comment: Formatting your dataframe for what? printing? passing to another function? What type of object should your output be: dataframe? Series? Python list? dict? etc. Please edit your question to add specifics.

Comment: Presumably in your starting dataframe, `New` is a column, and `3,2,4,5,8` is the index?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit different but you can nest a list as a value in a column inside a `DataFrame` in Python.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'new':['A','A','B','C','C'], 'val':[3,2,4,5,8]})
print(df)
     // apply a function 'list' on values and after
     // recreate a valid DataFrame where the field with lists
     // will be called 'up'

dfup = df.groupby('new')['val'].apply(list).reset_index(name='up')  
print("==============")
print(dfup)
```

The output is

```
  new  val
0   A    3
1   A    2
2   B    4
3   C    5
4   C    8
=============
  new      up
0   A  [3, 2]
1   B     [4]
2   C  [5, 8]
```

Normally, `groupby` is used to sum or some other aggregate function.

```
dfup = df.groupby('new').sum()
```

And the output is:

```
new
A      5
B      4
C     13
```

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner with `pivot_table()`. You can use `list` as `aggfunc`:

```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.DataFrame({'New': ['A','A','B','C','C']}, index=[3,2,4,5,8])

> df.reset_index().pivot_table('index', aggfunc=list, columns='New')

New         A    B       C
index  [3, 2]  [4]  [5, 8]

# You probably want the transpose...

> df.reset_index().pivot_table('index', aggfunc=list, columns='New').T

      index
New        
A    [3, 2]
B       [4]
C    [5, 8]
```

This seems close enough to what you want, but you can add code to remove the brackets around the list, when formatted for print. (e.g. convert index to string, and use string concatenate or `' '.join()` on it)

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you!